# How to construct a clean vocabulary from training text?

Tags: nlp

I am following the neural machine translation tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq) and notice that the datasets they use provide a [clean vocab file](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/nmt/data/wmt15.en-cs/vocab.1K.en). But when I come across a dataset (e.g. [Europarl v8](http://statmt.org/wmt17/translation-task.html)) that does not provide a vocab file, I need to construct a vocabulary myself using the following function.

```
def construct_vocab_from_file(file, vocab_file):
    # Read file, tokenize it and then sort it
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        raw_data = f.read()
        tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(raw_data)
        words = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
        vocab = sorted(set(words))

    # Write vocab to file
    with open(vocab_file, 'w') as f:
        for w in vocab:
            f.write(w + "\n")
```

However, the vocabulary constructed this way looks a little bit messy. [image]

The left one is from the clean vocab file while the right one with the black background (numbers are line number) is from the vocabulary constructed by me. This does not make me feel comfortable especially more than half of the vocabulary consist of these kind of special characters or numbers (e.g. 0, 00, 000, 0000, 0000003).

So my questions are:

1) Is this problematic?

2) Should I process it further and how?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the tokenization procedure you are using. Since you are using the wordpunct tokenizer, which basically sees anything resembling `\w+|[^\w\s]+` (http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) as a token, this is what you get.
Having these kinds of entries populate more than half of your vocab sounds like a lot, but obviously depends on your input data.
You could consider using a more sophisticated tokenizer, but considering that these kinds of entries are likely to have a very low frequency (i.e. most of them will be occurring only once in your data, I guess), I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Since you are using the Europarl stuff; there's also a tokenizer (perl) script in there, which you could use to output tokenized text, such that when you read it in python, splitting on whitespace means tokenizing. Not sure if the moses/europarl tokenizer is more or less sophisticated than NLTK's wordpunct one though.